# Who originally defined leverage scores to be the diagonal elements of $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, history, leverage

A nice description of leverage in the sense that I am using it is given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208242/hat-matrix-and-leverages-in-classical-multiple-regression) so I will not repeat it.

Who originally defined leverage scores to be the diagonal elements of $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$?

Comment: This is not really the definition: it's a *consequence* of a definition.  Belsley, Kuh, and Welsch (*Regression Diagnostics,* 1980) motivate it as follows. "The influence of the response value, $y_i,$ on the fit is most directly reflected in its impact on the corresponding fitted value, $\hat y_i,$ and this information is seen ... to be contained in $h_i$" (the diagonal element of the hat matrix).  See BK&W pp 16 - 18 for the subsequent analysis.

Comment: To the closevoter(s): I think this is perfectly on-topic here, and not opinion-based

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hoaglin & Welsch (1978)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2683469) say
*Thus we use the hat matrix to identify "high-leverage points." If this notion is to be really useful, we must make it more precise.*

This suggests the term 'leverage' is not widely used at that point, and I don't have an earlier reference.

Tukey (who also coined the term 'hat matrix') uses 'leverage' in a related sense in [a 1965 paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC219444/), talking about the amount of information in subsets of a sample, but not for regression. It's not used in the paper by Cook defining Cook's distance for measuring influence.

Comment: Sall (1990) includes a nice historical literature review https://doi.org/10.1080/00031305.1990.10475750