In computing the PRESS and Predictive $R^2,$ how should I handle points with a hat value of $1?$
I am computing the PRESS statistic in R, followed by the predictive $R^2,$ using the code:
PRESS = function(linear.model) {
    pr = residuals(linear.model)/(1-hatvalues(linear.model))
    PRESS = sum(pr^2)
    return(PRESS)
}

pred_r_squared = function(linear.model) {
    lm.anova = anova(linear.model)
    tss = sum(lm.anova$'Sum Sq')
    pred.r.squared = 1-PRESS(linear.model)/(tss)
    return(pred.r.squared)
}

The problem I am running into (and this is real-world data!) is that there is a data point for which the hat value (computed in the PRESS function) is $1.00000000.$ So when I subtract that from $1$ and divide, I'm getting negative infinity. It's only one data point (out of 156). Just delete? Or is there a more elegant way to prevent the computation from blowing up?

$h_{ii} < 1$ in a non-pathological model. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/208299/60613

What's a pathological model? The point in question happens to have basically zero residual $\left(2.38\times 10^{-13}\right).$ I want to know what's going on, and how to fix it.

If I just delete that point, I do get a predictive $R^2$ quite different (roughly half!) of the regular $R^2:$ $0.27$ versus $0.52.$ Overfitting?

A hat value that close to 1 means it is incredibly influential, which likely means that observation has a predictor value that is very different from the rest. This will result in a practically perfect fit at that point, because your data then is basically going through two points, the mean of everything else, and that point.
(BTW, this is a description in words of the pathological model Firebug linked to; this would be considered a "pathological" model in the sense that a linear fit is not appropriate for this data.)
You should see this pretty clearly in the standard diagnostic plots.

Yeah, the residual value at that point is essentially zero. Nice explanation!

What's your recommendation for fixing the problem? Simply deleting that point?

No, never simply delete a point from a data set based only on diagnostic criteria!

To make a recommendation, one would need the whole story. What's the question you're hoping to answer by fitting a regression and computing this? Why is that data point so different? What kind of conclusion are you hoping to make? Etc...

Actually, I think the problem has basically disappeared via model pruning. My model was overfitting (as determined by the predictive $R^2$ being much less than the regular $R^2$). Getting rid of statistically insignificant features made the problem go away. I think the particular point is likely a holiday weekend (measuring health care appointment volumes, that sort of thing).

Well... maybe. It seems more likely to me that now it's just hidden.
